# How to search in C if a binary file's content appears in another binary file?

Tags: c, file, binary

I need to take a binary file and search if its content appears in other binary files I read. Should I use the built-in functions?

Comment: [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) if they fit in memory.

Comment: @Acorn `strstr()` is for strings, not binary data.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, read the question too fast, sorry. [`memmem`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem) then, assuming OP has access to it (possibly running it on top of a memory mapped file).

Comment: If the files are small, you could use the in-memory functions others have proposed. But, if they are large, you should to use more sophisticated techniques, such as the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm). You should describe more fully the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two buffers storing the binary file in each of them using the command [`fread`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm). Compare the lines you want to search and count how many matching Bytes you have in a row 
for example:

```
int i = 0;
int isInfected = 0;
char* virusSign = 0;
int count = 0;
int size = 0;
int fileSize = 0;
int index = 0;
char* buffer = 0;
```

Note: "virus" in this case is the binary content I am searching for. While destFile is the file binary file I am searching in:

```
while (index < fileSize && !isInfected)
{
    if (virusSign[i] != buffer[index] && count != size - 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count == size)
    {
        isInfected = TRUE;
    }
    i++;
    index++;
}
if (virus != NULL)
{
    fclose(virus);
}
if (destFile != NULL)
{
    fclose(destFile);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain why did you do "count != size - 1", i didn't quite understand that part